# Where to keep sqlite db file in Java Dynamic Web Project?

Tags: java, sqlite

I am trying to use `Sqlite db` in a `Dynamic Web Project`. I am using [sqlite4java](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java/wiki/GettingStarted) for java to connect to the db. I have already created a db file and now trying to access it from my Dynamic Web Project. The code is like this -

```
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    SQLiteConnection db = null;
    SQLiteStatement st = null;
    try {
        db = new SQLiteConnection(new File("dbfile.dbf"));
        db.open();
        st = db.prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_Tblsignscores");
        // st.bind(1, minimumQuantity);
        while (st.step()) {
            res.append(String.format("ID: %d, Score: %d \n",
                    st.columnInt(0), st.columnInt(1)));
            // orders.add(st.columnLong(0));
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    } finally {
        st.dispose();
        db.dispose();
    }
    return res.toString();
```

but the connections always fails at `db.open()`.It says Nullpointerexception. I tried placing the dbfile inside `web-inf>lib`, `web-int`, project root, but nothing seems to work. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: The file is relative to the app, so you need getRealPath. This is almost never a good idea, however: configure it to a known external location instead.

Comment: even if I give a known external path, same error is thrown. maybe the problem is somewhere else. the sqlite4java is a wrapper of the sqlite dll file. it might be the wrapper is unable to locate the dll file.

Comment: That's why you should actually show the full exception.

Comment: I tried debugging the code. from `db.open()` the code directly goes to  `finally` block. And the null exception occurs at `st.dispose()`. anyways, since I am a bit short on time, I moved to using Sqlite JDBC driver. It's working. But if anyone can tell me what's the problem with this code that would be great.

Comment: Normally you wouldn't do a select using a prepare.

Answer (score 1):

I also get like your ploblem. I fixed it with my own solution but I am not sure it is good solution. The solution is using the `class-path`.

Web application directory struture

```
- app-root
    - WEB-INF
        - classes
            - mydb.db
```

program

```
protected Connection getConnection() {
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + this.getClass().getResource("/").getPath() + "/mydb.db");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return con;
}
```

Now, I don't need to worrry missing `db` file. It is sure at my class path directory.